# DocumentDB in Docker - "The authorization token is not valid at the current time."

Tags: python, azure, docker, tornado, azure-cosmosdb

I'm running a Python Tornado application in Docker, and part of the API involves connecting to DocumentDB for storage:

```
client = document_client.DocumentClient(config.uri, {'masterKey': config.key})
db = next((data for data in client.ReadDatabases() if data['id'] == config.db))
coll = next((docs for docs in client.ReadCollections(db['_self']) if docs['id'] == config.collection))
```

The authorization works perfectly and I've done many calls to the database with adding and removing documents. The issue comes up when I've left the Docker container running for a few hours (haven't counted exactly how long it takes) or when I leave the container up over night and check it in the morning, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
tornado1_1  |   File "api_app.py", line 76, in <module>
tornado1_1  |     class UserHandler(BaseHandler):
tornado1_1  |   File "api_app.py", line 82, in UserHandler
tornado1_1  |     db = next((data for data in client.ReadDatabases() if data['id'] == config.db))
tornado1_1  |   File "api_app.py", line 82, in <genexpr>
tornado1_1  |     db = next((data for data in client.ReadDatabases() if data['id'] == config.db))
tornado1_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydocumentdb/query_iterable.py", line 123, in next
tornado1_1  |     retry_utility._Execute(self._iterable._client, self._iterable._client._global_endpoint_manager, callback)
tornado1_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydocumentdb/retry_utility.py", line 48, in _Execute
tornado1_1  |     result = _ExecuteFunction(function, *args, **kwargs)
tornado1_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydocumentdb/retry_utility.py", line 81, in _ExecuteFunction
tornado1_1  |     return function(*args, **kwargs)
tornado1_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydocumentdb/query_iterable.py", line 114, in callback
tornado1_1  |     if not self._iterable.fetch_next_block():
tornado1_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydocumentdb/query_iterable.py", line 144, in fetch_next_block
tornado1_1  |     fetched_items = self.fetch_items()
tornado1_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydocumentdb/query_iterable.py", line 184, in fetch_items
tornado1_1  |     (fetched_items, response_headers) = self._fetch_function(self._options)
tornado1_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydocumentdb/document_client.py", line 225, in fetch_fn
tornado1_1  |     options), self.last_response_headers
tornado1_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydocumentdb/document_client.py", line 2349, in __QueryFeed
tornado1_1  |     headers)
tornado1_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydocumentdb/document_client.py", line 2206, in __Get
tornado1_1  |     headers)
tornado1_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydocumentdb/synchronized_request.py", line 168, in SynchronizedRequest
tornado1_1  |     return retry_utility._Execute(client, global_endpoint_manager, _InternalRequest, connection_policy, request_options, request_body)
tornado1_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydocumentdb/retry_utility.py", line 48, in _Execute
tornado1_1  |     result = _ExecuteFunction(function, *args, **kwargs)
tornado1_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydocumentdb/retry_utility.py", line 81, in _ExecuteFunction
tornado1_1  |     return function(*args, **kwargs)
tornado1_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydocumentdb/synchronized_request.py", line 100, in _InternalRequest
tornado1_1  |     raise errors.HTTPFailure(response.status, data, headers)
tornado1_1  | pydocumentdb.errors.HTTPFailure: Status code: 403
tornado1_1  | {"code":"Forbidden","message":"The authorization token is not valid at the current time. Please create another token and retry (token start time: Thu, 04 Aug 2016 04:30:53 GMT, token expiry time: Thu, 04 Aug 2016 04:45:53 GMT, current server time: Thu, 04 Aug 2016 15:11:11 GMT).\r\nActivityId: af4c602a-9413-4eb3-b270-b8a57fa2d973"}
```

As you can see, it can make a connection to the client, but it fails at the line    `db = next((data for data in client.ReadDatabases() if data['id'] == config.db))` and throws some weird error regarding time mismatch between the server and the token start time. As soon as I restart my computer (not just the container) it will work again for an indeterminate amount of time. I read on the [Azure Documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-secure-access-to-data/#working-with-documentdb-master-and-read-only-keys) the following tip:

> Tip:
>   Resource tokens have a default valid timespan of 1 hour. Token lifetime, however, may be explicitly specified, up to a maximum of 5 hours.

Not sure if that has anything to do with it or not.

Answer (score 0):

This can be due to your machine time drift(as compared to the server) that keeps on increasing until the difference is one hour.

In the exception message, you can see the lag between token start/end time and the current server time.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the auth tokens expire. So you'll need to generate another one.The error message says "Please create another token and retry".

Maybe you're creating the token when you create the container? You could try removing the container to force it to create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [HTTP Status Codes for DocumentDB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn783364.aspx) and your description, the status code `403` of the exception information means **`The authorization token expired.`**

So the solution is that create a new client connection instead of the old one via catch & handle the exception.

As references, there is a tip from the end of the article.

> **Tip:**
>
> Resource tokens have a default valid timespan of 1 hour. Token lifetime, however, may be explicitly specified, up to a maximum of 5 hours.

You can refer to the REST APIs [`Create a Permission`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn803932.aspx) or [`Replace a Permission`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt632100.aspx) to modify token lifetime via specify the value of the header `x-ms-documentdb-expiry-seconds`.